# Can't figure out trigonometry problem

Tags: trigonometry

**Problem**: Let $\triangle ABC$ have sides $a,b,c$. If $\angle A:\angle B:\angle C=4:2:1$, prove that $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=\frac{1}{c}$.

We are given background to Law of Sines and Law of Cosines, but I don't have any idea how to arrive at the equation.

Comment: What does $A : B : C = 4 : 2 : 1$ mean? Does this represent the ratio of the angles at A,B,C?

Comment: Did you try to solve this yourself? Please tell us what was your progress.

Comment: Angle size *roughly* corresponds to side length. So the ratios of the sides are also *around* $4:2:1$ If we take the side whose length is $1$ as our unit, we have side lengths $4, 2, 1$. Then we can see that $\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{3}{4}\approx 1$. What sayest thou?

Comment: @Aig OR the equality could be *falsitas*! Nice!

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard application of the sine rule, using the fact that $\frac{c}{a}=\frac{\sin C}{\sin A}$ etc. We know that $A = \frac{4\pi}{7}$, $B = \frac{2\pi}{7}$ and $C = \frac{\pi}{7}$. Now we are to show that $\frac{c}{a}+\frac{c}{b}=1$:
\begin{align*}
\frac{c}{a}+\frac{c}{b} &= \frac{\sin C}{\sin A} + \frac{\sin C}{\sin B}
\\&= \frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{7}}{\sin\frac{4\pi}{7}}+\frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{7}}{\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}}
\\&= \frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{7}+2\sin\frac{\pi}{7}\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}}{\sin\frac{4\pi}{7}}
\\&= \frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{7}(1+\cos\frac{2\pi}{7})+\sin\frac{\pi}{7}\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}}{\sin\frac{3\pi}{7}}
\\&= \frac{\sin\frac{\pi}{7}(2\cos^2\frac{\pi}{7})+\sin\frac{\pi}{7}\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}}{\sin\frac{3\pi}{7}}
\\&= \frac{\sin\frac{2\pi}{7}\cos\frac{\pi}{7}+\sin\frac{\pi}{7}\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}}{\sin\frac{3\pi}{7}}=1.
\end{align*}

Comment: There is a strong opinion (or rather, the [enforced site policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards)) that it is better not to answer to a question which is clearly a low quality post. You should encourage a person to improve a post instead. You can always leave a comment to a question.

Comment: Also, $1+\cos(2\pi/7)\ne 2\cos(\pi/7)$.

Comment: Muchas gracias for the answer.

Comment: @Aig I made a small typo, missed out a square on the cosine on the RHS - has been corrected, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$\angle A = \frac{4\pi}{7}$, $\angle B=\frac{2\pi}{7}$, and $\angle C=\frac{\pi}{7}$ (radians)

We know that in any triangle, the side opposite to largest angle is the largest side. The side opposite to the smallest angle, is the smallest size. (and the last angle and side) Sides $a$ and $b$ are both larger than $c$ and since the smaller the denominator, the larger the fraction, this seems logical. Let's formally prove this now!

Let $\angle C = x$. We know $\angle A = 4x$ and $\angle B = 2x$. We will find the sides of the triangle in terms of $x$.

Law of sines: $$\frac{a}{\sin 4x}=\frac{b}{\sin 2x}$$
Rearranging, we get $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{\sin 4x}{\sin 2x}=\frac{2\sin (2x) \cos (2x)}{\sin 2x}=2\cos 2x$.
.
Repeat this process for $\frac{b}{c}=2\cos x$.

We wish to prove $\frac{c}{a}+\frac{c}{b}=1$. (multiple original equation by $c$). We already found $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{b}{c}.$ To find $\frac{a}{c}$, we multiple the two ratios we have! Now we have $\frac{a}{c}=4\cos 2x\cos x$. Solving for the reciprocals we get: $$\frac{1}{4\cos 2x\cos x}+\frac{1}{2\cos x}=1$$ Since $x=\frac{\pi}{7}$, $$\frac{1}{4\cos \frac{2\pi}{7}\cos \frac{\pi}{7}}+\frac{1}{2\cos \frac{\pi}{7}}=1$$ which evalutes to $1$. Thank you DarkLordOfPhysics for finding a few mistakes.

Comment: $\frac{a}{c}$ lost a factor of $4$ it seems.

Comment: Also, $\sec{x}$ should be $\cos{x}$. It then works out!

Comment: I don't know how I even made that mistake... thanks for finding that :)